# test different density on eclipse emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Sorry for this basic question, I searched the archive but didnt really find a definite answer. It's about density and how the app works on different screens. It's a little more info than I can absorb, so I am wondering, if I test-run the app in eclipse on all different Built-in skins for the emulator (HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA and all the rest on the list) and it looks okej, can I then sleep well in the nights knowing that my app will look proper on most devices out there or do I have to mess with something else, like the Abstracted LCD density?

Thanks for helping!
Andreas

Comment: Do you mean to set a custom density number?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly i create custom layouts for portrait and landscape. It will be once out of 100 cases that you will land up on a device which runs android and has a peculiar screen, may be small or big... If then your App looks little weird, its then you need to replicate that screen in your Emulator... then create a custom layout named layout-small for this.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What about the picture sizes, would it make sense to make same images with different pixel sizes so for instance on a hdpi screen the button images wouldnt look too small, or too big on the ldpi screens?